# How do design a WCF service that can start a Task asynchronous and Gets it status

Tags: .net, wcf, architecture

I want to create a WCF Service that will start a long running Task and have the posibility to query the status of the thread.

My ideea is to create a class that implements this interface

```
public interface IProcess
{
    ProcessStatus GetStatus();
    void AsyncStartDataProcess();
}
```

`AsyncStartDataProcess` will create a new thread that will run a method to to some long running tasks.

Then have in the WCF Service a static object of IProcess type:

```
public static IProcess ActiveProcess = ProcessFactory.CreateNewProcess();
```

And then expose through ServiceContract two methods:

```
StatusResponse GetStatus();
StartProcessResponse StartProcess();
```

`StartProcess` method will call `ActiveProcess.AsyncStartDataProcess()` and `GetStatus` will call `ActiveProcess.GetStatus()`.

There will be only one active process for every request.
GetStatus and StartProcess will be accessed from an ASP.NET web application, and it can be accessed by multiple users.

Are there any problems caused by the fact that I am starting a long running thread during a call to WCF service? ( the response will get to the client and the thread will keep running ? )

Should I better use singleton instance in this case ? If yes, the previous question is applying in this case?

Comment: If you will use a singleton, in which thread will it live? Anyway you will have to start a new thread.
Just make sure there is no way to start 2 threads when 2 users calls StartProcess() simultaneously.

Comment: the initial idea was to create a new thread for the long running task, no matter the type of the service. Thanks for the input, I put a lock before I start the thread. I did some basic testing and it works good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your service's contract is well-designed (*IF* you are totally sure there will only be one long-running task). But I would not execute the long-running task in the class implementing the service. I would factor it out to another component.

If you have more than one long-running process, you could do this:

```
public interface IProcess
{
    ProcessStatus GetStatus(Guid id);     
    Guid AsyncStartDataProcess();
}
```